# Is there a easier / clearer syntax like Markdown that can compile into LaTeX?

Tags: compiler-construction, syntax, latex, markdown

I love LaTeX. Let's get that straight right off the bat.

The only thing I'm wishing for is a clearer syntax that compiles into LaTeX, like Markdown for HTML. This is because most of the simple document creation that I do (like taking notes in class), could be faster and improved if I could just type `1/2` instead of `\frac{1}{2}` and it compiles it into a neat fraction. I know about and use AucTeX, and it makes for faster typing, but it's still not very clear and more prone to syntax errors in general.

If such a simpler syntax exists that compiles into LaTeX, please tell me in the answers below. If there is nothing satisfactory, I would love to start an open-source project towards this goal, but I would like to know of existing alternatives first.

Comment: LaTeX *is* a simpler TeX already... The basic issue here is one of being able to do *anything*. Take the fraction example you chose: making it work, would make it harder to say when you wanted '1' followed by '/' followed by '2' all in the standard text mode and font (in the context of typing a date, perhaps)... So the question becomes "Which use cases a special enough to make them defaults at the expense of all the others?". Also note that Markdown *can't* do some things---that's the cost of being able to others very easily.

Comment: @dmckee: Well in the `1/2` example, I would expect it to turn `1/2` into a fraction only in math mode. Wouldn't that make sense?

Comment: @dmckee: But yes, what you said makes sense. I was just thinking that a lot of things that you do with LaTeX are a lot more common than others, and it would make sense to have a simplex syntax when you're interested in using LaTeX for quick note-taking or simple documents. If you wanted to create more complex documents and take advantage of its more obscure functionality, you would use the full syntax. I for one would love to use a shorter syntax when taking notes in class, for example.

Comment: Typesetting / as a fraction in mathmode might make sense, except that sometime you want to typeset fractions horizontally so that you can use them in a block of text. That may or may not be a good example, but when you try to do this you set yourself a huge problem in terms of prioritizing use cases. It probably *can* be done, but it may not be easy and certainly won't be universally applicable.

Comment: @dmckee: You're right. My idea, though, was to just choose the simpler use case by default, and have a functional looking document after quickly taking notes in class. Then, if you want to change some fractions into inline ones, you can edit the LaTeX code directly to suit that need. This simpler syntax would be great for rapidly churning out documents with some basic settings, and more fine-tuning can be done when you have more time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [Markdown to LaTeX script](http://rufuspollock.org/2008/06/23/markdown2latex/) exists for the [Markdown in Python](http://www.freewisdom.org/projects/python-markdown/) Markdown implementation. There is another [extension](http://www.freewisdom.org/projects/python-markdown/Available_Extensions) called [mdx_math](http://www.freewisdom.org/projects/python-markdown/mdx_math) that allows inline LaTeX math. The [Haskell Markdown to whatever converter, Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/), can have inline LaTeX math and can export to LaTeX. There are probably others in the [Markdown family](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown_extensions). However, none of these (AFAIK) give an alternate syntax for doing math.

There are a few [mathematical markup languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_markup_languages) according to Wikipedia. Although it is written in JavaScript, you might be interested in [ASCIIMathML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCIIMathML).

You will probably need to write something yourself, but a Markdown extension looked for blocks that used a clean syntax (like ASCIIMathML) would be neat.

Comment: Excellent, the ASCIIMathML script looks very similar to what I was thinking. Now if this were implemented to convert to LaTeX, and other stuff like sections and formatting were added to the simple syntax, it would be just what I'm looking for.

Comment: I reckon the best way to do it would be to extend Markdown so that, say, `~1/(a+b)~` blocks are treated as math and converted with something like ASCIIMathML.

Comment: Or you could modify Markdown so that the `\`` blocks are treated as math rather than as inline code.

Answer (score 2):

If you think only about the simplest cases, you're going to be in for a world of hurt.  `\frac{1}{2}` is waaay too simple.

What would you use for your simple syntax for each of the following:

`\frac{1}{x + 1}`

`\frac{1}{x} + 1`

`\frac{x^2}{x + 1}`

`x^\frac{2}{x + 1}`

`\frac{x}{{x + 1}^2}`

`\frac{x}{x + 1}^2`

I'll be very surprised if your first attempt doesn't include several duplicates (conflicts).

Comment: Just off the top of my head, this is what those examples would look like: `1/(x + 1)`, `1/x + 1`, `(x^2)/(x + 1)`, `x^(2/(x+1))`, `x/((x+1)^2)`, `(x/(x+1))^2`

Comment: And my simple syntax would automatically parse out parentheses into fractions and add parentheses (`\left(` and `\right)`) where they are required to make the equation more clear.

Comment: But what if you don't want parentheses? Or what if you do? If it was easy to figure it outautomatically don't you think Knuth would have done it?

Comment: @hadley: Well, if you think about it, you only really need parentheses around stuff to logically group them for an operation performed on them, like `sin` or an exponent. So it would look for that sort of case and put parentheses there. This approach would make functional equations quickly, and if you wanted to add or remove parentheses for just aesthetic or personal reasons, you could go and do that to the LaTeX source when you get more time later. The important thing would be that the simple syntax would be functional and readable.

Answer (score 2):

[Multimarkdown](http://fletcherpenney.net/multimarkdown/) uses ASCIIMathML syntax in double angle brackets:

```
<<x/2>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should really check [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) which has excellent integration between markdown and latex. What's nice is you can just drop latex inline to cope with the iffly bits for which markdown is too simple.

Answer (score 0):

I know of no other easier syntax for LaTeX.

However, there is [`TeXML`](http://getfo.org/texml/), which is an XML-to-TeX/LaTeX converter. It might sound weird at first, but it could make making your custom syntaxes much easier by just converting them to XML, then calling TeXML. TeX syntax is tricky: meaningful empty lines, TeX special characters, usually also lack of unicode... TeXML makes dealing with all this easier.

Answer (score 0):

I know you were looking for simpler code not a new editor, and you said you use AucTeX (which I don't so I don't know if this helps), but [TeXlipse](http://texlipse.sourceforge.net/) for Eclipse has some nice editing features which can make for faster input, including adding end braces } and end commands \end{env} and allow for tabbing out of braces. Just a thought.

Comment: Yep, AucTeX does similar things. I'm just not satisfied with that :)

Answer (score 0):

[reStructuredText](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html) can compile to LaTeX (the language itself is much simplier than TeX, though it still uses TeX syntax for formulas), see [Generating LaTeX with Docutils](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/latex.html) article. Various extensions to reStructuredText exist, like [Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/).

You can also take a look at [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) which can read math in any formats (including [ASCIIMath](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/asciimath.html)) and has a menu option to show math as TeX.